# MySQL insert/update/delete/select goes slow sometimes

Tags: php, mysql, database-performance

As I am using **InnoDB** as a database engine, the query goes slower sometimes it takes 20 seconds or more often.

I know the solution it can be done via **my.conf** to change the value of **innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit to 2** it can solve my problem I also want to do that but as I have shared hosting so they are not allowing me to do that.

**MySQL version: 5.6.32-78.1**

I also tried with MySQL query

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit';
+--------------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name                  | Value |
+--------------------------------+-------+
| innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit | 1     |
+--------------------------------+-------+
1 row in set
```

And i tried this query

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2;
```

but it is also not allowing me too because I don't have super privileges to perform this action.

I have database with **25 tables**, and in **4 tables** there are **4000+** records and in rest tables, there are below **100** records

So is there any other solution to speed up the query performance.? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is index set in your table?

Comment: @RaajNadar Yes it is.. but i also try to remove it but not helped so much. so i reverted as it is..

Comment: table structure and how many rows are there in the table?

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo i just edit my question please check

Comment: To discuss a slow query, please provide `SELECT ...`, `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`, and `SHOW CREATE TABLE ...`

Answer (score 2):

Use profile to check the cost time in each step;

1. `set profiling=1;`
2. Run you query;
3. Check the query:`show profiles;`
4. List the time cost: `show profile block io,cpu for query N;`

Find the step which has the high `Duration`

It shows like this
[image: profiles]
[image: list]

Possible problem: Index, Order by, File sort, Use temp table..

Comment: Have you `set profiling=1;`?  And `show profiles` shows the info list, in my answer, I run `select * from mysql.user` as the `slow query`, and the info list shows the ` slow query` has query_id `1`, so use show profile block io,cpu for query `1` ;

Comment: What's your MySQL version? Check the profiling by `show variables like '%profil%';`

Comment: it returned me like this "have_profiling YES","profiling OFF", "profiling_history_size 15"

Comment: Strange....if you `set profiling=1;` or `set profiling=ON;`, the variable profiling should be ON, and query info should be recorded....

Comment: Looks like Percona-Server, any info in i_s? Set ON the profiling and use `SELECT STATE, FORMAT(DURATION, 6) AS DURATION FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROFILING WHERE QUERY_ID = 1 ORDER BY SEQ;`

Comment: Yes i get the values after run those commands. set profiling=1;
show profiles;
show profile block io,cpu for query 1;

Comment: but i dont know why sometimes it is run faster and sometimes it takes 20 seconds to execute a simple query?

Comment: order by, group by, subquery, and temp table need a lot fo cup-time, if cpu-usage is high, the execute-time may not stable;  If buffer_pool_size is too low, MySQL will read data from disk, it also affects the  execute-time(read more from disk, execute longer); Execute plan also may affect execute-time, it's complex..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162395/discussion-between-nirav-joshi-and-green-blade).